# #finding the area of square PROGRAM

Tags: python, python-3.x

## Finding the area of square PROGRAM

```
print("Finding the area of a square")

height = input("Please enter the height of your square\n")

width = input("Please enter the width of your square\n")

area = height * width

print("This is the area of a " + height + " x " + width + " square, " + area)
```

> Error: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204744/typeerror-cant-multiply-sequence-by-non-int-of-type-str)

Answer (score 0):

Input in python is **string** type you must convert it to **int**:

```
area = int(weight) * int(height)
```

or

```
weight = int(input(---))
height = int(input(---))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Error: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

You can't multiply strings.

Convert your input to `int` using `int()` function.

```
height = int(input("Enter height"))
```

Answer (score 0):

height and width are of type str. convert it to int and try.

```
area = int(height) * int(width)

print("This is the area of a " + height + " x " + width + " square, %d" %area)
```