# convert a string to integer in django templates

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I am getting error when trying to multiply the below in django templates (multiply is a custom tag)-

```
{{ contact.cost|add:"0" |multiply:contact.rate }}
```

cost is of type varchar and rate is of type decimal in models.py. I tried putting in add:"0" for converting the string to integer first and then multiplying but it is still giving an error.

```
can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'decimal.Decimal'
```

What is wrong? Still very new to django, please help.

EDIT-

```
def multiplystr(x, y):
    val = Decimal(x)
    return Decimal(val * y)
```

Error-

```
[<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]
InvalidOperation
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204744/typeerror-cant-multiply-sequence-by-non-int-of-type-str)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing builtin to Django that converts strings to integers.

Your best bet is to either fix this in the view (fixing so that `contact.cost` is an integer) or in your custom `multiply` function so it can handle strings.

Something like below should work

```
def multiply(value, arg):
   value_as_int = int(value)
   return int(value_as_int * arg)
```

Comment: Thanks Henrik for the response. Why is contact.cost|add:"0" |multiply:contact.rate not working though? add:"0" by definition says that it will convert to integers?

Comment: @user2715898 it's your `multiply` function that is throwing the error. Most likely since the `add` can't add the `0` to the `contact.cost`. Without your `multiply` function source code it's hard to debug the issue.

Comment: Hi Henrik, tried this custome tags- I have rates in Decimal() so instead of int(), I have just put in Decimal- see the edited question but still giving an error

Comment: @user2715898 Can you paste some data? It seems as if something else is wrong.

Comment: yes it's the data, multiple places have n/a,N/A, N/a stored. Any good way of handling this or the usual if statements?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def multiplystr(x, y):
    valX = Decimal(x)
    valY = Decimal(y)
    return Decimal(valX * valY)
```